# How to Upgrade Amazon Elastic Beanstalk Linux 1 to Linux 2 for Django Application

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upgrade a Django application from AWS Elastic Beans Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.20 to Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.0.  It runs locally.  When I try and deploy to Elastic Beanstalk I'm getting the following error:

```
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/var/app/current/src/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: application = get_wsgi_application()
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: self._setup(name)
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Apr  6 10:30:48 ip-172-31-43-9 web: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

My file structure is:

```
.ebextensions
  01_packages.config 
  ...
.platform/hooks/postdeploy
  01_django.sh
src
  app1
  app2
  ...
  core
    folder 1
    ...
    settings
        base.py
        local.py
        aws.py
    celery.py
    ...
    wsgi.py
  ...
```

`core` is in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In anticipation of a better solution, my temporary solution is to move my `.ebextensions`, `.elasticbeanstalk` and `.platform` directories down 1 level.

It looks like this

```
src
  .ebextensions
    01_packages.config 
    ...
  .platform/hooks/postdeploy
    01_django.sh
  app1
  app2
  ...
  core
    folder 1
    ...
    settings
        base.py
        local.py
        aws.py
    celery.py
    ...
    wsgi.py
  ...
```

I do my `git push` to save to GitHub from the previous main directory and then move into `src` to perform`eb deploy`.  I'm not happy with the solution and consider it a workaround until someone can give me something better